# Android ViewPager with previous and next pages visible?

Tags: android, gallery, pager, android-viewpager, android-support-library

I am currently building a horizontal gallery of videos.

I'd like to make something like that with only one video centered and part of previous and next videos:
[image]

I first opted for a [Gallery](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Gallery.html) but its limitations made me look for something else. I'd like to show a page indicator and it is quite difficult to implement using a Gallery.

The second option was to go for a [ViewPager](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html) from Android Compatibility library. I found a way to implement a [page indicator](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator) over it. But now, how to partly show left and right pages?

Comment: see this. i had similar problem and this helps me.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13194666/how-to-set-viewpager-size?answertab=votes#tab-top

Answer (score 47, accepted):

I used a negative page margin to partly show the next and the previous pages. The fading edge property can be used to make previous/next page fade:

```
ViewPager examplePager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.exampleView);
examplePager.setPageMargin(-50);
examplePager.setHorizontalFadingEdgeEnabled(true);
examplePager.setFadingEdgeLength(30);
```

The lastest support package (revision 4, October 2011) is also required for this to work

Comment: This causes the pages to have a white gradient on the left, but the left screen still isn't visible, on an Android 2.2 using android-support-v4-r7. On which device did you test this?

Comment: @marmor I tested it on a lot of devices, most of them running Android 2.3.3, some Android 2.2 and even some Android 2.1 devices. I had no problem on any of the devices. Does a positive page margin work like expected? Perhaps your views don't have a transparent background so the current view may overlap the adjacent views?

Comment: I tested this on an HTC hero running 2.2, I have a pretty non-standard layout where the left fragment acts as a hidden action bar, so maybe this solution didn't work just in my case. I ended up solving this by applying a padding to the right fragment, thanks!

Comment: @Konrad: Thanks for this answer, the negative margin will changes based on the devices, I set the page margin as (-65) and i tested in two devices, HTC one and Xperia Z, in Z its looking good but in htc on the two pages are merged. how can i set this as globally?

Comment: setPageMargin takes in pixels, you probably want to use dp, there are methods for converting them here: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8309354/formula-px-to-dp-dp-to-px-android

Comment: First time while scrolling to right it cuts next item.But after scrolling to left it takes given effect.Please help.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Use this code in recyclerview and use snap helper

```
recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new 
LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, 
false);

recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    new LinearSnapHelper().attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);

 recyclerView.setScrollingTouchSlop(  recyclerView.TOUCH_SLOP_PAGING);
```

[more info about snaphelper layout](https://blog.mindorks.com/using-snaphelper-in-recyclerview-fc616b6833e8)