# How to re-position my location button in google mapv2 in android?

Tags: android, google-maps

I am writing an application in android using Google map-V2 API. I want to over lay action bar just as in the Google map application. And I enabled "My Location " button. The problem now is that my location button is under the action bar. Is there any way to re-position this button. I want to make an app some what similar to Maps. I am new to android so please help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can not alter the MyLocationButton in any way, but enable and disable it. There is already a [request](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4789&q=apitype=Android2&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Introduced%20Fixed%20Summary%20Stars%20ApiType%20Internal) for this.

Feel free to [disable](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/UiSettings#setMyLocationButtonEnabled%28boolean%29) the button and just implement your own one.

You would have something like this:

```
mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
```

Comment: please help, How can i add a button on top of a map. and how to get my location from the newly added button.

Comment: It would be better to open up a new question about this.

Comment: if i disable the MyLocationButton how can i show the location in the similar way?

Comment: Be sure to call mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

Comment: I am sorry...How this will help me. would't this enables the button?

Comment: I think I don't understand you.. you wanna disable the button and keep track of the location right? This works with the above suggestion. If you disable the button you can't show your location on the map with one click. Therefor you need your own implementation.

Comment: Thank's a lot it worked...:). i have one more doubt how to move map to my location when i click my custom button?

Answer (score 14):

You can set [padding](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/map#map_padding) to the map.

This solved the problem - overlays over the map on the top (I used 48 dips, but you can overlay action bar and then get actual height of it (*?android:attr/actionBarSize*))

```
mapFragment.getMap().setPadding(0, dpToPx(48), 0, 0);
```

(DP to PX function is from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17410076/574474))

Comment: Setting the padding programatically worked for me, while setting it in the layout xml didn't

Answer (score 9):

**You can reposition your location button easily**

```
View plusMinusButton = suppormanagerObj.getView().findViewById(1);
View locationButton = suppormanagerObj.getView().findViewById(2);

// and next place it, for exemple, on bottom right (as Google Maps app)
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlp = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)     locationButton.getLayoutParams();
// position on right bottom
rlp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP, 0);
rlp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
```

[image: Chage LocationButton]
you can also set padding after setting alignment of the location button

```
mMap.setPadding(0, 0, 30, 105);
```

Comment: How to set in bottom | left?

Comment: You have to use aMap.setPadding. This method is responsible for setting position of the Location image ICON.

Answer (score 3):

I solved this problem in my map fragment by re positioning my location button to the right bottom corner of view using code below,
here is my Maps Activity.java :-

add this lines of code in onCreate() method,

```
   SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapView = mapFragment.getView();
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
```

and here is onMapReady() code :-

```
  @Override
        public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
            mMap = googleMap;
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

            // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
            LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));

            if (mapView != null &&
                    mapView.findViewById(Integer.parseInt("1")) != null) {
                // Get the button view
                View locationButton = ((View) mapView.findViewById(Integer.parseInt("1")).getParent()).findViewById(Integer.parseInt("2"));
                // and next place it, on bottom right (as Google Maps app)
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)
                        locationButton.getLayoutParams();
                // position on right bottom
                layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP, 0);
                layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
                layoutParams.setMargins(0, 0, 30, 30);
            }

        }
```

I hope, this will solve your problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of the findViewById solutions, I used the findViewWithTag to get a reference to the button.  Using a string seemed more readable and reliable to me.

```
    View myLocationButton = mMap.findViewWithTag("GoogleMapMyLocationButton");
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlp = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) myLocationButton.getLayoutParams();
    rlp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP, 0);
    rlp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use GoogleMap.setPadding(left, top, right, bottom), which allows you to indicate parts of the map that may be obscured by other views. Setting padding re-positions the standard map controls, and camera updates will use the padded region.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/map#map_padding

Comment: Nice trick. Any way how to get Current padding? GoogleMap.getPadding method() does not exist...