# Layout params getWidth() returns zero

Tags: android, xml, width, layoutparams

i have a `RelativeLayout` here's the code :

```
<RelativeLayout
   android:id="@+id/camerapreview"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:layout_margin="10dp"
   android:background="#000">
</RelativeLayout>
```

its a camera preview for the camera application, i set the `width` to `match_parent`.

and here is my java code :

```
RelativeLayout preview = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.camerapreview);
int w = preview.getWidth();
LayoutParams params = preview.getLayoutParams();
params.width = w;
params.height = w;
preview.addView(mPreview);
```

basically i decalaired the width of the `RelativeLayout` to `match_parent` to be dynamic to the width of any device. But i want the view to be square so i used the `java code` abave, but every time i ran the program this line `int w = preview.getWidth();` returns zero. I must have missed something, help please :D thank you.

Comment: where are you writing this code? is it onCreate()?

Comment: yes @GopalRao its on onCreate()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this may help you...

```
    RelativeLayout preview = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.camerapreview);
    int width = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = preview.getLayoutParams();
    params.width = width;
    params.height = width;
    preview.setLayoutParams(params);
```

here `preview` will occupy entire screen width... and it will be square shaped...

Comment: this is probably right, but the camera preview is stretched horizontally, maybe because the width's value is pixels, how can i convert that to DP?

Comment: @GreenFox see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4605527/converting-pixels-to-dp and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8309354/formula-px-to-dp-dp-to-px-android. there are many outcomes when you type **convert pixels to dp in android** in Google search...

Answer (score 3):

The size of view cannot be calculated until its parent is calculated you can force that with following code:

```
view.measure(MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
int widht = view.getMeasuredWidth();
int height = view.getMeasuredHeight();
```

there is three way to do this, see this [link](http://www.sherif.mobi/2013/01/how-to-get-widthheight-of-view.html)

**EDIT**

you can use this too.

```
RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.camerapreview); 
ViewTreeObserver vto = layout.getViewTreeObserver(); 
vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() { 
    @Override 
    public void onGlobalLayout() { 
        hs.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this); 
        int width  = layout.getMeasuredWidth();
        int height = layout.getMeasuredHeight(); 

    } 
});
```

Comment: RelativeLayout preview = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.camerapreview);
  preview.measure(MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
  int width = preview.getMeasuredWidth();
  LayoutParams params = preview.getLayoutParams();
  params.width = width;
  params.height = width;
  preview.addView(mPreview);

i did this and its still zero, did I do it right?

Comment: see my Edit @GreenFox, did you see the link?

Answer (score 1):

Layout has width 'match parent' . So if it hasn't views (is empty) width = 0.
Solution: 
Add views to layout 
Or set width to 'fill parent'