# Get image size in pixels from DPI (dot per inch) android

Tags: android, tesseract, dpi

I try to get minimum image size for tesseract, from 300 `dpi` to `pixel`, in android. I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17410076/719212) tell me how to convert dp to pixel, but seems it isn't what I need, as `dp = dip = Density-independent pixel` (correct me if I'm wrong). For example, if I have an image with size 1024 x 768 pixels, then how I can get its size base on 300 (dpi) dot per inch?

Comment: Careful, dp == dip (density independent pixel), but dp != dpi (dots per inch). Exactly what is the conversion you need?

Comment: I need to convert dpi (dots per inch) to pixels, says I have image with size 1024 x 768 pixels, and I need to get the size 300 dpi

Comment: Dots per inch cannot be converted to pixels, they measure different things. It's exactly like trying to convert km/s into meters.

Comment: ok, so you mean dpi is density of pixels on image, while pixel is a size of image?

Comment: Yes, of an image or a display (e.g. the nexus 5 has a 450 dpi screen, that is also 1920 pixels tall -- which means that it's 4.2 inches tall). coming back to your original question, I'm not entirely sure what conversion you need :/

Comment: Ok, I got it. Thank you. Just because `tesseract` require image has 300 dpi resolution, so i don't know how to do with it. You may want to answer my question then I can accept it.

Comment: do you want to resize the image

Comment: @R4j I tried to expand on it a little bit. Hope it's useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A bitmap doesn't have an "inherent" density, only a resolution (i.e. `x by y` pixels).

An image file may contain information about DPIs, but that's only for mapping to *physical dimensions* (i.e. for printing). For example, an 800px * 600px image with a resolution of 96dpi will be printed as 8.33in * 6.25in, while the print area will be smaller for a higher resolution.

Therefore, "pixels to dpi" is not a valid conversion -- it's kind of like converting distance into speed.

I'm not sure about the requirements for tesseract, but if it receives a **bitmap** as an input then it will be "processing pixels", so I don't think the 300dpi requirement makes sense -- that's probably a rule of thumb to obtain a good result from scanned text of particular (physical) font size.