# FAB with anchor in coordinator layout has extra margin in android pre-lollipop

Tags: android, android-layout, floating-action-button, android-coordinatorlayout

I have a `CoordinatroLayout`with `FloatingActionButton`. Here is my code:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar_layout"
        android:layout_above="@+id/actionbar">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="120dp"
                android:minHeight="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="@color/toolbar_color" />


            <ScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                >

            </ScrollView>


        </LinearLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:clickable="true"
            app:fabSize="mini"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_action_edit"
            app:layout_anchor="@id/toolbar"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/toolbar_color"            />
        </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

But it appears differently in lollipop and pre-lollipop devices.

Lollipop:

[image]

Pre-Lollipop:
[image]

Actually I haven't add any margin. But FAB has margin in pre-lollipop devices.

I have also seen this problem in [cheessesquare](https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare) sample. It shows different margins too. What is the problem?

Comment: What happens when you add margins?Does it double the space in pre lollipop?

Comment: it's possible this post will be useful [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30687888/android-design-library-floating-action-button-padding-margin-issues](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30687888/android-design-library-floating-action-button-padding-margin-issues)

Comment: @JudeFernandes Yes, it doubles the space in pre lollipop.

Comment: @DmitryArc, Thank you. The link was helpful. So it is a bug in android!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I dont think you want to place them without margins. If I understood it right, you've done this to see whats going on in different versions of android.

> You can use `app:useCompatPadding="true"` and remove custom margins to maintain **same margins** across different versions of android

[image: android studio code]

Proof of concept

[image: design view]

Comment: I still have no clue why no other answer has described the same. I had the same problem, and now its fixed :)

Comment: Thank you! I have changed the selected answer.

Answer (score 5):

According to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30687888/android-design-library-floating-action-button-padding-margin-issues), it seems to be a bug in android design library. It says that:

> in API <20, the button renders its own shadow, which adds to the
>   overall logical width of the view, whereas in API >=20 it uses the new
>   Elevation parameters which don't contribute to the view width.

So I have to provide two resource files for margin:

res/values:

```
<dimen name= "fab_margin_right">0dp</dimen>
```

And in res/values-v21:

```
<dimen name = "fab_margin_right">8dp</dimen>
```

Answer (score 3):

Since 22.2.1 version of support and design library, previous answer is no longer true. There is no extra padding if FAB is inside CoordinatorLayout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/button_show_qr"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_action_edit"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/primary"
        app:borderWidth="0dp"
        app:elevation="4dp"
        app:fabSize="normal"
        app:rippleColor="@color/primary_dark"/>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

This code will produce following FAB on every Android version.

[image]

Comment: Thank you but I was using support library 23.0.0 when I faced the problem.

Comment: but there is if its in another layout like linear and etc :/
android is silly and an insult to developers