# Fab in Lollipop shows strange shadow on long press

Tags: android, android-layout, shadow, floating-action-button

I am using the **FloatingActionButton** in a CoordinatorLayout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab_add"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:tint="@color/white"
    app:fabSize="normal"
    app:layout_anchor="@+id/view_pager_imageformat_carousel"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_playlist_add_black_24dp"
    app:useCompatPadding="true" />
```

and it works fine with most Android Apis, but in **Android 5 and 5.1** it shows a **boxed shadow when it is pressed**:

[image: fab]  ->  [image: fab pressed]

I tried setting clipChildren to false in the CoordinatorLayout, without any effect and looked through other available options wihtout success so far.

Has anyone encountered the same problem and came up with a solution?

Comment: What support lib version do you use?

Comment: I am using version 25.3.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turned out that the culprit was `useCompatPadding`.

Removing it solved the shadow problem.

To fix the margins I used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30687888/android-design-library-floating-action-button-padding-margin-issues)
which basically uses custom margins with two different styles, default and ond for api 21+

But this is in fact an ugly solution and the margins are not perfect, so I am open to better solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set elevation:

```
app:elevation="0dp"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add `app:rippleColor="@color/transparent"` to set the ripple color to transparent.