# Unexpected margins in RelativeLayout showing up only on device

Tags: android, margin, floating-action-button, android-relativelayout

I am facing a very unusual situation.
I have defined a layout file with some icons arranged in a RelativeLayout and aligned vertically. The thing is that I did not set any margin between them and on the preview screen and on the emulator they appear as expected, but on the device they are always separated by a consistent margin.

My question is: why are those margins showing up? How can I remove them?

Here you can see the difference between the result on [emulator (API 26)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aybpm.jpg) and [physical device (API 19)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPZ4E.jpg).

Speaking about code, here below there is my layout XML file.

```
<com.example.rusia.madcall.design.CustomSlidingPaneLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
tools:context="com.example.rusia.madcall.MapsActivity"
android:id="@+id/sliding_pane_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<!-- PLEASE DO NOT CHANGE CHILDREN ORDER -->

<!-- CONTENT 1 (on the left): The Master Pane -->
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/master_pane"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<!-- CONTENT 2 (on the right): The main view -->
<com.flipboard.bottomsheet.BottomSheetLayout
    android:id="@+id/bottomsheet"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <!-- Map -->
        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <!-- Icons on the left-top -->
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <!-- Menu Icon -->
            <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/fab_menu"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="start|top"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_white_24dp"
                android:visibility="visible"
                app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary" />

            <!-- Icons & Descriptions -->
            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/left_icons"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/fab_menu"
                android:visibility="visible"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp">

                <!-- 1st icon: NEAR ME -->
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/near_me_box"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="0dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/fab_near_me_description"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="21dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="21dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/bg_description_left_icon"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                        android:text="@string/near_me"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:visibility="gone" />

                    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                        android:id="@+id/fab_near_me"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="start|top"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_near_me_white_24dp"
                        android:visibility="visible"
                        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary" />

                </RelativeLayout>

                <!-- 2nd icon: ADVANCED SEARCH -->
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/advanced_search_box"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/near_me_box"
                    android:layout_marginTop="0dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/fab_search_description"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="22dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="22dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/bg_description_left_icon"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal|center"
                        android:text="@string/advanced_search"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:visibility="gone" />

                    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                        android:id="@+id/fab_search"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="start|top"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_search_white_24dp"
                        android:visibility="visible"
                        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary" />

                </RelativeLayout>

                <!-- 3rd icon: SETTINGS -->
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/advanced_search_box"
                    android:layout_marginTop="0dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/fab_settings_description"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="22dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="22dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/bg_description_left_icon"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal|center"
                        android:text="@string/settings"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:visibility="gone" />

                    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                        android:id="@+id/fab_settings"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="start|top"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_settings_white_24dp"
                        android:visibility="visible"
                        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary" />

                </RelativeLayout>

            </RelativeLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab_location"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="end|top"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_my_location_white_24dp"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary" />

    </FrameLayout>

</com.flipboard.bottomsheet.BottomSheetLayout>
```

Comment: this may be because your preview screen is with lower dpi and the emulator is with higher dpi.

Comment: they have different screen sizes, so the margins have different real sizes too.

Comment: @PankajMundra my preview screen and my emulator do match, the thing that does not match is the physical device.

Comment: @MykhailoVoloshyn I explicitly set android:layout_margintTop to 0dp.

Comment: [Use layout inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rcwk6.png) and see what is going wrong.

Comment: Thanks @azizbekian. Your answer brought me to the solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @azizbekian suggestion I got to the true issue and I solved it. I am sharing my findings and my solution.

First of all I noticed in the Layout Inspector that the FloatingActionButton(s) had mPaddingTop, mPaddingBottom, etc. all set to 42dp. I investigated about FloatingActionButton(s) padding and indeed I found a well-known issue (discussed already [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30687888/android-design-library-floating-action-button-padding-margin-issues) in StackOverflow). 
**The problem is then related to FloatingActionButton** and not to RelativeLayout. More specifically, on older versions of Android, these buttons come with a default all-around padding.

By combining the answers, I solved the issue by adding the following properties to all my FloatingButton(s):

```
app:useCompatPadding="true"
app:elevation="0dp"
app:pressedTranslationZ="0dp"
```

This has the effect to remove the built-in padding and get the simple icon. You can then add your custom padding or margin with the common properties android:layout_margin or android:padding.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EPP1S.jpg) an example of the final result with a padding of 10dp between the buttons.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score -1):

You need to develop different XML for different screen sizes.

To check your device dpi you can download [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=it.gerdavax.displayinfo) app.

To create different layouts create a folder in resource and name it as layout-sw320dp

change sw320dp to sw600dp, sw700dp, according to your screen dpi.

Different devices will automatically take the accurate layout XML according to device dpi.

For reference check [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

I hope this information will be useful to you.