# Get screen resolution of device

Tags: android, resolution, screen-resolution

I used following method to get the screen size:

```
public static Point getScreenSize(Context context)
{
    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    int w = wm.getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
    int h = wm.getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();
    return new Point(w, h);
}
```

On my samsung galaxy s6, this method returns 1080x1920... Although my device has a resolution of 1440x2560.

Why? Is there a better method to get the screen resolution that works on newer phones reliable as well?

**EDIT**

I need this method in a service! I don't have a view/activity for help, only the application context! And I need the REAL pixels

Comment: I had a scrollview as my root for one of the activities in which I needed this. I simply used to get `scroll.getHeight()` and `scroll.getWidth()` on it. No hassles at all and was perfect.

Comment: Check one of the answers at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8309354/formula-px-to-dp-dp-to-px-android. There should be one valid for your case.

Comment: I believe **getWidth()** and **getHeight()** are deprecated in favor of **Point**.

Answer (score 8):

The best way to get your screen resolution is from `DisplayMetrics` :

```
DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
int width = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
int height = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
```

Comment: No, as getMetrics subtracs decor size. Use getRealSize()

Answer (score 7):

If you are targeting for API >= 17, try with the `getRealSize` method of the `Display` class:

```
WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
Point size = new Point();
wm.getDefaultDisplay().getRealSize(size);
String resolution = size.x + "x" + size.y;
```

for me, it worked.

Answer (score 2):

Use this one:

```
private static String getScreenResolution(Context context)
{
    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    display.getMetrics(metrics);
    int width = metrics.widthPixels;
    int height = metrics.heightPixels;

    return "{" + width + "," + height + "}";
}
```

Comment: returns the same values... I really need to know the real physical size of the device

Comment: You can't get device physical size in all device because that depends on device as well.
ie.
Check two devices
Nexus 5 
Lenovo K3 both size is 1080X1920

but when you call above function then get different values.

so you check hardware button with device and marge those height with device height so at end you can get actual physical size which manufacture displaying at product.

Comment: How can i call this method from my class

Comment: WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) this.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    display.getMetrics(metrics);
    int width = metrics.widthPixels;
    int height = metrics.heightPixels;

Answer (score 1):

> `Use this.`

```
DisplayMetrics metrics; 
int width = 0, height = 0;
```

> `In your onCreate method.`

```
 metrics = new DisplayMetrics();        
 getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);


 height = metrics.heightPixels;     
 width = metrics.widthPixels;
```

Comment: returns the same values... I really need to know the real physical size of the device

Answer (score 1):

The API returns the number of pixels an app can use, so this is the correct result.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 Display mDisplay = context.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();

 mDisplay.getWidth();
 mDisplay.getHeight();
```

Note that this code uses ***deprecated*** APIs.