# Calculate total device height and width

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio

I want to calculate the total device width and height. I have a device 600x1024 and the following code shows only 552 width when landscape and 972 height portrait.

```
DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();  
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);  
int height = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
int width = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get Screen width and height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4743116/get-screen-width-and-height)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46472932/6156989

Answer (score 0):

You are getting smaller size because the navigation bar takes some space, and `getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics)` will return only *available screen size*.

There is no official-documented way to get the full screen size, however there are some workarounds:

1. You can get the screen size *after your acticity enters full-screen mode*. This should hide the navbar.
2. You can get the size of the navbar and add it to the screen size you got in your code:

   ```
   Resources resources = context.getResources();
   int resourceId = resources.getIdentifier("navigation_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
   if (resourceId > 0) {
       return resources.getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
   }
   return 0;
   ```
3. You can get the whole screen size:

   ```
   public static Point getRealScreenSize(Context context) {
       WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
       Display display = windowManager.getDefaultDisplay();
       Point size = new Point();

       if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 17) {
           display.getRealSize(size);
       } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 14) {
           try {
               size.x = (Integer) Display.class.getMethod("getRawWidth").invoke(display);
               size.y = (Integer) Display.class.getMethod("getRawHeight").invoke(display);
           } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
           } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
           } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {}
       }

       return size;
   }
   ```

Methods 2 and 3 are hacks, so keep in mind that they have a chance to fail on some devices.