# How to set ViewPager size

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-viewpager

[image: Layout]

Could I set the viewpager's size?
like the image1,
I want to show 3-page in the same screen.

If not, I can only use LinearLayout?

Comment: there is no such options in ViewPager. You will have to implement your own ViewGroup or probably try to use Gallery

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Your problem is similar to one CommonWare's blog. [Multiple-View ViewPager Options](http://commonsware.com/blog/2012/08/20/multiple-view-viewpager-options.html) 
There are three approach. One of those is override `getPageWidth()` in your PagerAdapter:

```
@Override public float getPageWidth(int position) { return(0.5f); }
```

The others are more complicated but there're attach source and long explanation so i don't copy here.

Comment: Only working solution for me so far. Needed exactly three pages visible. Love one-line solutions. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this, you have to create `ViewPager` with 3 pages, which takes one layout for page 1 and 3 and different one for page 2. In layout for page two define all 2,3,4. 
In short you have merge pages 2,3,4 into one.