# ViewPager2 how to change child drawing order?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-viewpager2

I am trying to implement ViewPager2 with overlapping items (carousel like component).
Everything seems fine, but my center item get overlapped by next item. I want my center item be in front of any neighbour items.

See image below:

[image]

When you use **ViewPager1** class we can  override **getChildDrawingOrder**

```
@Override
    protected int getChildDrawingOrder(int childCount, int i)
```

See example solution here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25439543/how-to-achieve-a-viewpager-with-previous-and-next-page-shown-and-bigger-focused)

But ViewPager2 cannot be derived and extented (since ViewPager2 class is final). What should I do?

Comment: You can try to add two lines in your dimens.xml file 
<dimen name="viewpager_next_item_visible">26dp</dimen>
<dimen name="viewpager_current_item_horizontal_margin">-42dp</dimen>

Comment: Margins does not help much, since they donot change child draw order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I finally decided to get rid of ViewPager2 and get back to ViewPager1 since I can override **getChildDrawingOrder** function, then I followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25439543/how-to-achieve-a-viewpager-with-previous-and-next-page-shown-and-bigger-focused) to achieve what I actually wanted.  Hope when ViewPager2 will be soon finalized and they will make ViewPager2 class non final

Comment: Checkout this repository i have added many `Transformation` for `Viewpager2`   it will help you : https://github.com/askNilesh/Viewpager-Transformation

Answer (score 2):

Under the hood `ViewPager2` contains a `RecyclerView`, so if you want to change the child drawing order you'll need to do it on the `RecyclerView`.

While it isn't an officially supported solution you can get access to the `RecyclerView` by asking for the first child on your view pager. See this comment:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/134912610#comment3

`val recyclerView = viewPager2.getChildAt(0)`

Once you have access to the `RecyclerView` you can add a `ChildDrawingOrderCallback`.

https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.ChildDrawingOrderCallback

The code below works if you have exactly 3 pages and want the middle page to be drawn on top of the other pages.

```
  recyclerView.setChildDrawingOrderCallback { childCount, i ->
        when (i) {
            0 -> 0
            1 -> 2
            2 -> 1
            else -> throw IllegalStateException("Expected 3 items")
        }
    }
```

Comment: to support variable number of items I have implemented the 'setChildDrawingOrderCallback' as setChildDrawingOrderCallback { childCount, i ->
            IntArray(childCount) { it }.reversedArray()[i]
        }