# How can we create a cylindrical viewpager?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, carousel

I am trying to implement a cylindrical view pager something like this(Instead of square pages I need circular pages).

[image]

I tried [ViewPager with previous and next page boundaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13914609/viewpager-with-previous-and-next-page-boundaries][2])

How can I make a view like this?

Comment: i think there are answers in the link you have provided.Have u tried those?

Comment: search for carousel slider

Comment: @anirugh yes,But the previous and the next pages are not coming beneath the selected page.

Comment: @user2894326 Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use [Fancy Cover Flow](https://github.com/moondroid/CoverFlow), this is exactly what you looking for

```
<it.moondroid.coverflow.components.ui.containers.FeatureCoverFlow
        android:id="@+id/coverflow"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        coverflow:coverHeight="@dimen/cover_height"
        coverflow:coverWidth="@dimen/cover_width"
        coverflow:maxScaleFactor="1.5"
        coverflow:reflectionGap="0px"
        coverflow:rotationThreshold="0.5"
        coverflow:scalingThreshold="0.5"
        coverflow:spacing="0.6" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Use viewpager with padding, and use PageTransformer  for this purpose.[refer this quiz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35475178/how-can-i-create-viewpager-with-previous-and-next-page-preview-and-centred-one)