# How can i create ViewPager with previous and next page preview, and centred one zoomed from preview

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-pagetransformer

```
viewPager.setClipToPadding(false);
viewPagerMusicCategory.setPadding(width/3, 0, width /3, 0);
viewPagerMusicCategory.setPageMargin(40));
```

I got next and previous preview by above code. But now i need that zoom effect for centred page.
[image: eg]

Thanks in advance

Comment: I would suggest to scale the view using ViewPropertyAnimator.

Comment: For example `view.animate().scaleX(1.5).scaleY(1.5).setDuration(250);`

Comment: you want to room the center on interactively or just do a zoom animation when the image comes to center

Comment: i want to zoom the center one

Comment: how can you set width in setPadding

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
viewPagerMusicCategory.setPageTransformer(false, new ViewPager.PageTransformer() {
        @Override
        public void transformPage(View page, float position) {
            Log.e("pos",new Gson().toJson(position));
            if (position < -1) {
                page.setScaleY(0.7f);
                page.setAlpha(1);
            } else if (position <= 1) {
                float scaleFactor = Math.max(0.7f, 1 - Math.abs(position - 0.14285715f));
                page.setScaleX(scaleFactor);
                Log.e("scale",new Gson().toJson(scaleFactor));
                page.setScaleY(scaleFactor);
                page.setAlpha(scaleFactor);
            } else {
                page.setScaleY(0.7f);
                page.setAlpha(1);
            }
        }
    }
);
```

....

Answer (score 0):

Use it in `recyclerview` and use snap helper

```
public class CenterZoomLayoutManager extends LinearLayoutManager {

    private final float mShrinkAmount = 0.15f;
    private final float mShrinkDistance = 0.9f;

    public CenterZoomLayoutManager(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CenterZoomLayoutManager(Context context, int orientation, boolean reverseLayout) {
        super(context, orientation, reverseLayout);
    }


    @Override
    public int scrollVerticallyBy(int dy, RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, RecyclerView.State state) {
        int orientation = getOrientation();
        if (orientation == VERTICAL) {
            int scrolled = super.scrollVerticallyBy(dy, recycler, state);
            float midpoint = getHeight() / 2.f;
            float d0 = 0.f;
            float d1 = mShrinkDistance * midpoint;
            float s0 = 1.f;
            float s1 = 1.f - mShrinkAmount;
            for (int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); i++) {
                View child = getChildAt(i);
                float childMidpoint =
                        (getDecoratedBottom(child) + getDecoratedTop(child)) / 2.f;
                float d = Math.min(d1, Math.abs(midpoint - childMidpoint));
                float scale = s0 + (s1 - s0) * (d - d0) / (d1 - d0);
                child.setScaleX(scale);
                child.setScaleY(scale);
            }
            return scrolled;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int scrollHorizontallyBy(int dx, RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, RecyclerView.State state) {
        int orientation = getOrientation();
        if (orientation == HORIZONTAL) {
            int scrolled = super.scrollHorizontallyBy(dx, recycler, state);

            float midpoint = getWidth() / 2.f;
            float d0 = 0.f;
            float d1 = mShrinkDistance * midpoint;
            float s0 = 1.f;
            float s1 = 1.f - mShrinkAmount;
            for (int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); i++) {
                View child = getChildAt(i);
                float childMidpoint =
                        (getDecoratedRight(child) + getDecoratedLeft(child)) / 2.f;
                float d = Math.min(d1, Math.abs(midpoint - childMidpoint));
                float scale = s0 + (s1 - s0) * (d - d0) / (d1 - d0);
                child.setScaleX(scale);
                child.setScaleY(scale);
            }
            return scrolled;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }

    }
}
```

Use it in `recyclerview` and use snap helper

```
recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
CenterZoomLayoutManager layoutManager = new CenterZoomLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);

recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        new LinearSnapHelper().attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);

recyclerView.setScrollingTouchSlop(  recyclerView.TOUCH_SLOP_PAGING);
```