# Custom viewpager imageslider?

Tags: android, xml, android-viewpager

[image: I want to create something like this]

Although This is a solution [ViewPager with previous and next page boundaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13914609/viewpager-with-previous-and-next-page-boundaries) but it has limited scroll to only visible current image and does not work when i try to scroll from extreme left or right.

I want side images from left and right to be a little smaller and centre image to be on focus and larger like the image shown and with the indicator and text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure that got you right, but something similar I've done with:

```
pager.setClipToPadding(false);
pager.setPadding(50, 0, 50, 0);
```

**UPD.**

[ViewPager indicator](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ViewPagerIndicator)

In order to scale not visible fragments, try to use **setOnPageChangeListener**, and scale *position - 1* and *position + 1* fragment's view. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8785221/retrieve-a-fragment-from-a-viewpager) how to take reference on fragment from ViewPager.

Comment: I'll try again with your suggestion ! Thanks 
But what about different height of margin fragment and center fragment? and the indicator ?