# Implement Horizontal scroll view like carousel in android?

Tags: android, carousel, horizontal-scrolling, horizontalscrollview, coverflow

How to implement horizontal scroll view like carousel in android

**My Required o/p screen**
[image]

When we scroll item should be centre and show previous and next item screen pieces like attached screen

Comment: refer [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13914609/viewpager-with-previous-and-next-page-boundaries)

Answer (score 0):

You can set your required screen or layout inside Scroll View tag.  like bellow .

```
  <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="380dp"
            android:background="@drawable/pagebg0"
            android:scrollbars="vertical || Horizontal"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_below="@+id/heading"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

 </ScrollView>
```