# Showing partial of prev/next view in Xamarin.Forms w/ CarouselView

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am very new to Xamarin.Forms and I stumbled upon the github project [CarouselView](https://github.com/chrisriesgo/xamarin-forms-carouselview). I think it is almost perfect for what I want to do. I want to adapt it to show the previous and next views in the list. I don't need to worry about the content within those views. I just want to be able to modify each view so that I can see a preview of the previous and next item in the list. Kinda like the image below. Can anyone guide me in the right direction on how to achieve this?

[image]

Comment: Hi! Did you solve this?

Comment: I never did. I guess Xamarin is still (I think) working on the CarouselView. I havent checked up on this recently so maybe it is done? I havent been doing much Xamarin stuff lately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CarouselView is now part of Xamarin Forms. They added property **PeekAreaInsets** which takes in thickness value. Adjusting it will result in making items partially visible.
Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Old question of mine, but yes, now-a-days they have it pretty much built-in. I marked it as answer since it is the answer technically going forward.

Answer (score 0):

Carousel Page of Xamarin.Forms has an event so you can handle the change, this is something you can do:

```
CarouselPage t = new CarouselPage();
t.CurrentPageChanged += (object sender, EventArgs e) => {
    if(t.CurrentPage.Title == "Title 1"){
      //Then Change your number to 2 or 3 or what ever
      //Your Label.Text = 2,3,4 maybe handle this with a switch.
      //3/5 Page
    }
};
```

Comment: I may have to reword my question but I dont need the Title text changed. I want to basically change how each "view" is drawn so that I can see the previous and next view but only partially.

Comment: Ooooh I got you, I thought you wanted something like an indicator of the page (3 of 5 pages), but there is component for that (only for iOS tho): https://components.xamarin.com/view/Alliance.Carousel if that is not a good solution then you will have to create a custom renderer (for iOS and Android) for that: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/19395/carousel-view-custom-renderer-alternative

Comment: Well the control I listed above is using a custom renderer for iOS and Android but I am unsure how to tell it to draw the individual views to be smaller so I can see the previous and next view.

Comment: Looks like a custom renderer is the way, here is some insights on Native Android: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13914609/viewpager-with-previous-and-next-page-boundaries

Comment: Cool thanks. Ive seen that done for Android and I tried it but just can get it to draw the same. Was hoping someone could give me some pointers or sample code maybe?