# Design swipe activity android

Tags: android, android-layout, swipe, android-tabbed-activity

I need to make a layout similar to that [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jmdVP.jpg).
I wish it were shown all the registered images and their attributes and a button to add the user would select an image and define the attributes of it. I do not want a complete example that ordered but at least one direction than I use to do the layout. By my research I should perhaps use a swipe view. Has anyone seen something similar?
Thank you

Comment: ViewPager for the top part and RecyclerView for the bottom part. A LinearLayout to put both inside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ViewPager to display cards like in top part.
[ViewPager with previous and next page boundaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13914609/viewpager-with-previous-and-next-page-boundaries)

And use a ListView or RecyclerView to show the bottom part. https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/getting-started-with-recyclerview-and-cardview-on-android--cms-23465