# Design switch cards android layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-designer

I need to make this

[image]

Does anyone have any guidance on how this should be done?
Swipe Layout? View Page?
I know it sounds complex but if anyone has any material, thank you!

Help me!!!

Comment: It's not that complex actually. Check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13914609/viewpager-with-previous-and-next-page-boundaries It will help you a lot

Comment: Thank you very much, helped me a lot !!!